# how to add [node:title] field in drupal view?

Tags: views

I have use path auto module ,and I am trying to get url path using title node. exp: ,if space is coming in title path auto module remove space and put " - " but when I put [title_1] filed I am not getting same pattern as compere to path auto module .

Comment: do you  want to add tokens inside view using replacement patterns or you want to add content title field ?

Answer (score 0):

As I can remember node title is the first thing we see, after creating a view of content type.Answer to question "it is possible to add node title as field in view", would be yes.Though I am not sure if this was sure issue,might be if you can post a screenshot of your view can be of some help.

If in case you want node title as token to be used as replacement pattern.You can simply add the title field and keep the field exclude form display. And later you can use [node:title].

Comment: I have use path auto module ,and I am trying to get url path using title node. exp:<a href="club-info/[title_1]" data-caption="[field_job_title]"> ,if space is coming in title path auto module remove space and put " -  " but when I put [title_1] filed I am not getting same pattern as comper to path auto

Comment: @NikunjJagad Have you created title_1 as custom field? Your comment is different to question in your post

Comment: Yes I have added title_1 as custum field